# Putting adverts on my website

Tags: advertising

I'd like to start putting ads on my site but *I'm quite fussy about the way things look* so I'd like to have attractive adverts that work as a feature of the website as opposed to the nasty garish ones you occasionally see out there.

BuySellAds.com do what I'm looking for.  They don't accept your site unless it gets more than 100,000 hits per month so I can't use them.  The ads on http://net.tutsplus.com/ are the sort of thing I'm looking to include in my site.

What are my options here? Which companies offer this kind of service?

I would use AdSense but I don't like the look of the text ads, in-fact I know that I don't even read them if I see them. I do however spend a lot of my time looking at, and clicking on, the attractive image based ads you see on sites like [smashing mag](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) and [freelance switch](http://freelanceswitch.com/)

Comment: What is your site about?

Comment: ah, yes, good question.  It's music related at the moment but we're working on expanding to offer web-design tutorials etc...  I've gone and set up adsense, which is far better than I thought it would be.  Thanks to everyone who made suggestions:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people prefer text ads since they're less obtrusive and don't take up any significant bandwidth. But AdSense also offers graphic ads if I'm not mistaken.

Your other option is to sell your ad space manually, which is what the tutsplus sites do. However, that's a network of very large sites that has plenty of ad space as well as traffic to sell. Not many people are going to be coming to you directly for purchasing ad space if you're getting less than 100k page views per month, unless you're the dominant site in some niche market.

Comment: thanks I've gone with AdSense since, as you pointed out, they allow graphical ads and are pretty good ad matching them up with the content.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [The Deck](http://decknetwork.net/), used by a lot of fussy people, including 37signals, Daring Fireball, Kottke, and many others. It targets "creative, web and design culture" sites, so John Conde's question is valid.

Comment: yeah, I like the look of the Deck.  thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

Anthonyg's suggestion of TheDeck is a good one. Another option to consider is [Project Wonderful](http://www.projectwonderful.com/).

We really need to know more about your content. The best ad networks are very targeted for both advertisers and host sites.

Comment: thanks I like both of those options, but have decided to go with AdSense for now.  Will keep those others in mind for later on if I feel like a change.

Comment: oh, and the content is really random but mainly music related